# why the following range does not print out in python?

Tags: python, range

I have the following code in python:

```
def main():
    for i in range(-10, -100):
        print(i, end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but it print out nothing, but if i change the main function as:

```
def main():
    for i in range(-100, -10):
        print(i, end=' ')
```

it print out the expected result, what is the reason that the first one does not work?

P.S, I found the following example code in python tutorial:

```
range(-10, -100, -30)
  -10, -40, -70
```

then why this works, just because it added a step(-30)?

Answer (score 3):

The default `step` value for [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function is `1`. So, for your range to work, your 1st argument(`start`) must be smaller than the 2nd argument(`end`).

If you have the 1st argument(`start`) larger than 2nd argument(`end`), you can never reach the `end` value by adding step of `1` to `start`. In that case, you can give a step value of `-1` to go in opposite direction:

```
for i in range(-10, -100, -1):
```

now `i` will take the value `-10`, `-11`, `-12`, so on, till `-99`.

Answer (score 0):

A small simulation to the function `range([start ,] stop [, range])` with positive range (default being 1) is

```
def range(start, stop, range):
    lst = []
    while start < stop:
       lst += [start]
       start += range
    return lst
```

so if `range(-10, -100)` will fail `start < stop` , thus will print nothing.

However, if you used `range(-10, -100, -1)`, the range is negative thus the simulation will differ by replacing `start < stop` to `start > stop`. it will work, however will print the numbers from -10 till -99 the reverse of the second function